# Why does my Keras Custom Layer only gets called once?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow1.15

I have to work with tensorflow 1.15 and need a custom layer. A very simplistic layer can look like this:

```
class Dummy(keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, units=32, input_dim=32):
        super(Dummy, self).__init__()
        self.cnt = 1
    def call(self, inputs):
        self.cnt += 1
        return inputs
```

If I use this Dummy Layer in any architecture the variable cnt was only set to two. What am I missing?

Here is a very simplistic dummy script to shwocase my issue:

```
import numpy as np
import keras
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Conv2D, Activation
from tensorflow import set_random_seed
from numpy.random import seed

seed(312991)
set_random_seed(3121991)

class Dummy(keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, units=32, input_dim=32):
        super(Dummy, self).__init__()
        self.cnt = 1
    def call(self, inputs):
        self.cnt += 1
        return inputs  

# creating the input image
input_img = np.ones(shape=(8,8,3))

#adjust range
input_img_adjusted = input_img / 255
target = input_img_adjusted[:,:,0:2]

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(2, (3, 3),input_shape=input_img.shape, padding='same'))
model.add(Dummy())
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))

opt = keras.optimizers.Adam(0.001)
model.compile(optimizer=opt,
              loss="mean_absolute_error")

hist = model.fit(np.array(2048*[input_img_adjusted]),np.array(2048*[target]),epochs=100,batch_size=32)

print("called the Dummy Layer:", model.layers[-2].cnt)
```

My assumption would have been that it is something like 32,32*100 or something similar.

Comment: What does variable "cnt" stand for?

Comment: it is just a simple counter in the dummy layer to count up how often the the call function was called

Comment: the function call should be called more often than once, right? https://keras.io/guides/making_new_layers_and_models_via_subclassing/ Here the call function implements the compution, thus it should be called more often

Comment: Your assumption is unfortunately wrong, that is not how TensorFlow works, the layer is called once per phase (train or test) and used to build a computational graph which is actually used for computations, that is why you see this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Have to use `tf.Variable` and `assign_add` for initialization and adding

```
class Dummy(keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, units=32, input_dim=32):
        super(Dummy, self).__init__()
        self.cnt = tf.Variable(1, trainable=False)

    def call(self, inputs):
        self.cnt = self.cnt.assign_add(1)
        return inputs
```

Comment: Thank you, when I print it out the value with model.layers[-2].cnt.eval(session=sess) it is still 2

Comment: Don't reassign `self.cnt` in `call` and it will work. I.e., remove `self.cnt = ` in `call`